# array formula refer to cell above

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, circular-dependency

i have this problem that really bothers me.

i have a google sheet that i need to make a serial number on.

![AJ2;AJ] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ8P9.png)

with AH-202302 and then followed by a serial number.
as you can guess, 2023 is the year, 02 is the month that refer to B2:B column.

then i have this formula:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsuTh.png)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B3:B);;IF((AJ3:AJ)<>(AJ2:AJ);1;AK2:AK+1)))
```

that start at AK3. and i set AK2 cell to 1, so i can i tried to simply add 1 to the next cell of the array formula.

as you can guess, it triggers circular dependency and since my data is quite big, if i turn on iterative calculation, my sheet is frozen.

so, please, can you help me to solve this problem.

all i need is an array formula that add 1 to above cell, and, preferably without turning on circular dependency, or if it is required, without freeze my sheet.

thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

i want to answer my own question..

i've solved this.

so, all you need is `COUNTIFS` function;

this is the solution of my problem:

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(AJ2:AJ);;Countifs(AJ$2:AJ;AJ2:AJ;B2:B;"<="&B2:B)))
```

so this formula is counting the number of values of `AJ2:AJ` and using 2 criterias.

```
Countifs(AJ$2:AJ;AJ2:AJ...
```

1. first it count the number of a values of a value in `AJ2:AJ`. the `$` sign on `AJ$2` is used to lock the table so it doesnt move down along the array formula.

   `....;B2:B;"<="&B2:B)))`
2. then the second criteria count along the array formula of the value that is referred to, based on a growing number in `B2:B`, which is timestamp column. you can replace the timestamp column with `=row()` function to have the same result.

thats it. hope it helps.

*)disclaimer, since i am newbie on this, by any means, there is big possibility that i am wrong. so please correct me if so.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to add 1, you can use SEQUENCE. For example:

```
=Sequence(COUNTA(AJ2:AJ))
```

For other cases, you can use SCAN to create an ARRAYFORMULA that refers to the previous cell, but I think it's simpler this way

UPDATE:

```
=MAP(B2:B,AJ2:J,LAMBDA(bval,ajval,IF(ISBLANK(ajval),,COUNTIFS(B2:bval,">="&bval,AJ2:ajval,ajval))))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. I need the sequence to restart at 1 when the value of AJ2:J is changing.

Comment: Hello, that wasn't clear. If all the same elements are together you could do something with SCAN. But I've adapted your formula with MAP, since I'm not sure it's going to actually make the sequence as you expect. Try the update and let me know!